# Indexpath.row not working while getting record from NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to load the data `UITableView`which is coming from webservice. Everything is working fine. But, whenver the record is being displayed in `UITableView` using `-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method i'm getting exception like below-

[image]

Here is my code -

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell; //= [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Reuse_Cell"];
    UILabel *label = nil;

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];

        label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [label setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [label setNumberOfLines:1];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Trebuchet MS" size:18]];
        [label setTag:1];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:label];

    }

    if (!label)
        label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];

    [label setText:[[webserviceRecords objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"catName"]];
    [label setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 5.0, 225.0, 35.0)];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = RGBACOLOR(151.0, 191.0, 69.0, 1.0);
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.layer.borderColor = RGBCOLOR(214, 218, 1).CGColor;

    return cell;
}
```

My Array records -

http://pastie.org/7120406

Custom `init` method

```
- (id)initwithInteger:(NSInteger )integer
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        startingpage = integer;
        webserviceRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

`NumberofRowsInSection`

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"Row count - %d", [webserviceRecords count]);
    return [webserviceRecords count];
}
```

Comment: mark a breakpoint and step into....

Comment: show me your response array .

Comment: Please show how you are initializing webserviceRecords array.

Comment: Please check null. I think there is some null in your array. Thats why its crashing

Comment: @Bhargavi I've initalized my array in my `ViewController`'s init method.

Comment: Put break point in init method and check if it is going into it. I guess your array is not initializing

Comment: @Bhargavi I checked there also. Its working fine.

Comment: try to print your array. check if it contains value or not?

Comment: Can you show your code in init method ?

Comment: @Nirav Yes, it prints the array value.

Comment: how many rows in your tableview?

Comment: are you giving like this [webserviceRecords count]; for number of rows?

Comment: where are you adding the values to the webserviceRecords i think your array's count is zero

Comment: NSlog your record before the set text line.

Comment: Can you paste your numberOfRows method ??

Comment: @Praveen are you using ARC ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Nope i'm not using arc.

Comment: @Manohar Yes its printed 5.

Comment: @praveen:once post your - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section  method?

Comment: wat value does it print before setText in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Bhargavi [This is my records](http://pastie.org/7120477) which is coming from webservice. It was a thai language.

Comment: @Praveen: Just initialise the label after if(cell == nil) not inside just paste after the if condition

Comment: @Praveen Do you really have any label with tag 1 in your cell ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Yes i'm having.

Comment: @Praveen Just check no other view have same tag. Make sure your code reads label correctly.

Comment: @Praveen are you able to print the values before setText

Comment: @Bhargavi http://pastie.org/private/pp9rdmoupetwijasp67joa Yes i checked too :(

Comment: @LochanaRagupathy No i can't print it before setting text

Comment: NSDictionary *myDay = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *dateStringTemp = [myDay objectForKey:@"catName"]; use it

Comment: @Praveen how do you add the NSDictionary to your array can you post that code

Comment: @Praveen according to that image you are having NSDictionary instead of array.

Comment: On which line you are getting that error ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Yes you were right. I fixed it

Comment: @Praveen, write question with error log always, you can save your time and other people time as well who are trying to gave you answer.

Comment: @iAmbitious Yes. I'll do that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really a silly mistake was there. I've parsed the `JSON` data directly into my `NSMutableArray` I've parsed like below first -

```
webserviceRecords = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutableData options:0 error:&error];
```

Instead of this i've fixed this like below -

```
NSArray *array = nil;
array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:mutableData options:0 error:&error];
webserviceRecords = [array mutableCopy];
```

It helps me to fix my issue. Thanks for responsing my question.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the cell's `selectedBackgroundView` before checking that the cell has a value. You should check if the cell is nil first before doing that.

On a side note, you may find it much easier to display your array using the free Sensible TableView framework. The framework generates all the cells automatically from your array (including all the detail views), and can even fetch the data from the web service directly if you wish. Should save you a lot of headache and manual work. Hope this helps.